# Truncate String that has an embebed translation Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, truncate

I need to truncate a String at ROR.

```
<%= t("activerecord.values.payment.status_detail.#{detail}") %>
```

if I put

```
<%= t("activerecord.values.payment.status_detail.#{detail}".truncate(30) %>
```

if gives me a method error.

What is the best approach to resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say exactly without your error pasted but it looks like you are missing a closing bracket as `t` is a method, of which you want to truncate the result.

Your code should be:

```
<%= t("activerecord.values.payment.status_detail.#{detail}").truncate(30) %>
```

Comment: Yes, it's correct.
The thing that I'd like to add to this answer, it's not a good approach (to use variable for translation) I assume that's why you got errors.

To avoid it, it would be better to add additional check for that translation, this way you will avoid errors (if you wan't to keep variable usage).